# Adding Views to layout runtime, going ahead when the line ends: How To?

Tags: android, layout, view

I need to add views in a layout going to a new line at the end of one, filling every line from left to right. Imagine the layout is a paper and every word you write is a textview, and you have to write a long text. I don't even know which kind of layout I should use, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by 

"in a layout going ahead at the end of the line." 

?

Comment: sorry, i didn't explain very well. Anyway i edited the question, it should be clearer =)

Comment: As i know, there is no default layout in android doing that (*going to a new line at the end of one*). I think you need to create a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a `LinearLayout` set to an horizontal orientation. Something like the below. I have used two `TextView`s but you can use whatever kind of view you'd like. They will stack horizontally to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Item 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Item 2" />

    <!-- etc. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but this just fills the line from left to right, I need to go to a new line when one line ends too.

Comment: I see. There is no default layout that does that. You could build your own custom layout to do that but that would be quite some work. Can't you just use a TextView and fill it with the text you want? It has word-wrap and supports bold, italic and underscore text. If you need something more sophisticated than that you're stuck with building your own wrapping layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with nested LinearLayouts. Start with a vertical LinearLayout and a horizontal LinearLayout inside it. Then to add a View:

- measure the View (let's call it 'myView').

Then:

```
if(currentHorizontalLayout.getChildCount==0 || 
    myView.getWidth() > currentHorizontalLayout.getWidth()-currentHorizontalLayout.getChildAt(currentHorizontalLayout.getChildCount()-1)).getRight()){

    currentHorizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    verticalLayout.addView(currentHorizontalLayout);
    currentHorizontalLayout.addView(myView);
}
```